# When watching video full screen online, screen goes grey

Tags: video, lightdm, youtube

When I have watched a video online (usualy with YouTube video's), be it with Firefox or Chrome and press the button to exit full-screen mode, my laptop screen turns grey and there seems to be nothing I can do about it but enter TTY2 with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f2</kbd>, login and type `sudo restart lightdm` and log back in, resulting in loss of work.

[image: Example]

I own an ASUS N76VM laptop and it's running Ubuntu 12.04.

Offcourse I don't want this to happen and I'd rather make it so that it doesn't happen; instead of a sollution for after it has happend, but any sollution rather then restarting `LightDM` would make me happy.

Comment: Did you enable _Legacy Fullscreen_ in Compiz Workarounds?

Comment: I downloaded compizconfig, went to workarounds and enabled Legacy Fullscreen. Now we wait...

Comment: @Danatela Nope.. I just watched a video on youtube through Chrome on Ubuntu. Again, after clicking 'exit full screen' the same error occurred again.

Answer (score 0):

Your FlashPlugin may crashed, install adobe flash plugin from ubuntu software center,

[image]

if it not installed your system install it.

Comment: That is already installed